# Graphlets calculation of unweighted graphs

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I am using igraph library in r. It provides graphlets function to calculate graphlets of a graph in r. But it only works for unweighted graphs. What if I want to calculate graphlets of below unweighted graph.

```
library(igraph)
g2 <- graph.formula(A:B - A:C, X:Z - X:Y - X:B, C:Z , C:X )
g2
plot(g2)
```

then how to find the graphlets and graphlet counts of graph g2 that is unweighted.

Comment: Hmm where did you read that it only works for unweighted graphs (link + quote)?

Comment: @lukeA "http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/Graphlets" here it says that it models weighted graphs.

Comment: where did you read that it only works for unweighted graphs

Comment: When i use it for the above example the process will not give any result it will run and after some time the r session will get aborted.

Comment: I think it doesn't support unweighted graphs.

Comment: In the question you wrote _"But it only works for unweighted graphs"_. Now, you write _"I think it doesn't support unweighted graphs"_. I'm confused and don't understand what your actual problem is. Anyways... check out the example in the answer.

Comment: @lukeA thanks for the solution. In the below example you have added edge weights as 1. Then it would be converted in a weighted graph.

Comment: @lukeA Can  a R package ergm.graphlets be used in this case. I haven't found any proper example or document describing this package.

Comment: I don't know, I never worked with graphlets and touched only the surface of igraph/graph modelling. Give it a try and post a new question if you got stuck somewhere.

Comment: @lukeA Ok thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example based on `?graphlets`:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1); par(mfrow=c(2,2))
g2 <- graph.formula(A:B - A:C, X:Z - X:Y - X:B, C:Z , C:X )
E(g2)$weight <- 1
lo <- layout.auto(g2)
gl2 <- graphlets(g2)

plot(g2, layout=lo)
for (i in 1:length(gl2$cliques)) {
  V(g2)$color <- "white"
  V(g2)[gl2$cliques[[i]]]$color <- "red"
  plot(g2, layout=lo)
}
```

[image]

You may want to look at the example in `?graphlets` to add e.g. the edge weights.